# What's the better and fastest PHP Framework to learn?

Tags: php, frameworks

I've been using Cake PHP but I'm kinda "lost", I mean, I've made the tutorials and already did some works on it. But I'm not finding this framework that much "easy" to work. I'm thinking about going to another framework. What you guys recomend me ?

Yii, CodeIgniter, Zend or Symfony (or even another one) ?

Thank you

Comment: I think CodeIgniter is the second option if not cakephp

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DimVEvuOm_g&feature=plcp check this out, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like CodeIgniter. It is VERY easy to use and expandable. It also has a decent sized user base so finding help is fairly easy. Good luck!

[Here](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) is a comparison of PHP Frameworks.

Comment: In that site, there is a top list (http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) and Yii appears with more votes. I think I'll check this Yii, and then later (if needed) I'll try CodeIgniter. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

If you want something easy to use, I'd really recommend CodeIgniter. It took me literally just a few minutes to pick up the basics of it and I really hadn't used any framework before.

I also used Yii, but it's fairly rich and it felt unnecessary for the project I was doing. But, it isn't too challenging and I'd recommend it if you want something closer to Ruby on Rails (if you have experience with that). Just make sure you're comfortable with command line for Yii.

Answer (score 0):

Within the last few months, I used CakePHP, Zend and Yii for 3 different projects.  My personal favorite is still Yii, because it just seems to make the most sense.  It's also quick to get up and running.  The Gii tool is also helpful to quickly create your Models/Controllers and Views. So in answer to your question of "easy", I think Yii is the way to go. Zend is great for large enterprise applications or if you need great PHP libraries (which you can also use in other frameworks).  CakePHP is pretty easy to use, but I personally don't have as much experience with it.  I've never used CodeIgniter.